# Enable 3G button missing on iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, settings, cellular-carriers

I bought a secondhand iPhone 4s recently with iOS 7.0.4 installed.
I'm in Indonesia and I am using Telkomsel as my cellular provider.
When I am using it, the battery is decreasing fast. So I updated the iOS to 7.1.1.
But, what I got is the battery decreasing faster, and my iPhone is so hot, especially at Micro-SIM card area. **Is this normal in iOS 7.1.1 at iPhone 4s?**

What I want to do to decrease the heat is changing the network. My iPhone always using 3G connection, so I want to change it to 2G because I rarely use the 3G connection.
The "Enable 3G" toggle button should be at Settings → Cellular → Enable 3G, but mine is gone!

[image]

I compare it with my friend's iPhone which can switch 2G and 3G, and i suspect 1 thing, Carrier. I can see Carrier in Settings → General → About (EE 16.0).

[image]

I've been googling and found that this Carrier setting can hide this Enable 3G button, because they want to stop using 2G.
**Is it true, this Carrier setting is hidden the Enable 3G toggle button?**
**then, How to change it to Telkomsel (my cellular provider)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you buy your phone from someone in the UK (where the EE network is available)?

[According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1970) your phone should automatically update carrier settings when you connect to a new network. I assume you have the correct APN defined? If you're not sure, take a look [here](http://www.unlockit.co.nz/mobilesettings/) - having the incorrect APN *may* prevent the update from working.

Comment: No, i bought it from seller in Indonesia. I think he has relation that live in UK.

Comment: When i insert my micro sim (telkomsel), my iPhone can't access the internet. the solution i can find in internet is set the APN, and Apple says it can be set at settings. But i can't find it in my settings, so i download the APN settings at unlockit.co.nz.
but, it not change the Carrier and my iPhone doesn't automatically update Carrier settings. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

jailbreak is the answer for that... When you use your local Carrier, you can already use 3g enabling it in your iPhone settings.